# How to make a Sliding Window Transformation?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning

I try to preprocess my data for a Direct Multi-Step time series forecast but I have some problems when trying to transform the Dataset.

**Thats the Theory:**

[image]

I tried to use shift():

```
df['target_1'] = df['Close'].shift(1)
df['target_2'] = df['Close'].shift(2)
df['target_3'] = df['Close'].shift(3)
df['target_4'] = df['Close'].shift(4)
```

Thats the output:

[image]

Does anyone have some experience with this type of problem or could give me a good advice on where I can learn more about it since I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Do you not just want df['Close'].shift(-1)? I think you're just shifting it the wrong way (according to your example). You can then use .dropna() to remove the last few rows.

Comment: Yes you're right! That change fixed the problem. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from the comments in case any one searches for this problem.

The issue is that when a positive shift is applied, it shifts the rows DOWN. To shift the rows up (as was the desired case here), a negative shift can be applied.